# How to unsubscribe all observers from the observable side?

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-scala, reactivex

With rxscala, we can subscribe on the observables like this:

```
val stream = Observable.just(1, 2, 3)

stream.subscribe(x => doSomething(x))
stream.subscribe(x => doSomething(x))
stream.subscribe(x => doSomething(x))
stream.subscribe(x => doSomething(x))
```

Is it possible to unsubscribe all the observers(there are 4) from the `stream` side?

Comment: Could you store the Subscriptions returned by `subscribe` into a CompositeSubscription? Then you can unsubscribe `CompositeSubscription`.